# How to print this array elements in table format using ReactJS in Visual Studio Code Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

const people = [ { name: 'James', age: 31, }, { name: 'John', age: 45, }, { name: 'Paul', age: 65, }, { name: 'Ringo', age: 49, }, { name: 'George', age: 34, } ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show json array to any sort of table. Here I provided an example using `material-ui`

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-example-c70kr)

**Example:**

```
import React from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const rows = [
  { name: "James", age: 31 },
  { name: "John", age: 45 },
  { name: "Paul", age: 65 },
  { name: "Ringo", age: 49 },
  { name: "George", age: 34 }
];

export default function TableExample() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Age</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.age}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am using VisualStudio Code in that I am getting error

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Paper' in 'E:\ReactJSPrograms\hello-world\src'

Comment: may you have some issue in your environment. you can delete `node_modules` folder and re-install node using `npm install`

Comment: I does not need any styles. Please remove  styles and share code please

Comment: HI I have removed style. please check it.